# QtCreator Google Test Code Coverage

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, code-coverage, googletest

I am trying to do code coverage on my test. Already found this http://www.robertwloch.net/2013/06/generating-lcov-coverage-with-qtcreator/ and thought that this is exactly what I am looking for. But the problem is that I can't do it. Installed everything, added in .pro file, typed arguments and ... only got errors.

So then found this https://github.com/3Hren/QtCreatorCoveragePlugin/wiki and thought that it would be good too. But I can't even do qmake on sources. If it's not a problem I got already installed QtCreator but at this point I don't know what to do.

Maybe somebody knows some other method to get code coverage ?